# What is the right ffmpeg output format for playing a video to webcam using v4l2-loopback in linux?

Tags: linux, debian, ffmpeg, v4l2

please can someone show me the new syntax for sending videos to webcam using ffmpeg and v4l2loopback?

It used to work perfectly until I updated and upgraded recently

the previous syntax i use is:

```
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback

ffmpeg -an -re -i inputvideo.mp4 -f v4l2 -vcodec rawvideo /dev/video0
```

and the error I get is:

```
[v4l2 @ 0x55a452b3a400] ioctl(VIDIOC_G_FMT): Invalid argument
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- 
Conversion failed!
```

I attached a screenshot of the error message

[view image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kk2Cr.jpg)
The full code with the error is:

```
ffmpeg -an -re -i virtualcam.mp4 -f v4l2 -vcodec rawvideo /dev/video0
ffmpeg version 3.4.2-2+b2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Debian 7.3.0-21)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=2+b2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'virtualcam.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.16.100
  Duration: 00:08:08.36, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 377 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 480x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 376 kb/s, 22.77 fps, 22.77 tbr, 11384 tbn, 45.54 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> rawvideo (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[v4l2 @ 0x55a452b3a400] ioctl(VIDIOC_G_FMT): Invalid argument
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- 
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: Looks like you have to upgrade the loopback driver: https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/issues/172

Comment: Please let your question be a question. Your solution should be an answer. Read [*Can I answer my own question?*](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) Your edit is available [here](https://superuser.com/revisions/1333353/2), you can paste it as a proper answer into the answer field.